# How to represent number that is the smallest possible value larger than another number?

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

How would I represent the number, i, that is one increment larger than $x$, where an increment is infinitely small.

For example, if $s \in (1,2)$, $i$ would be the smallest number $s$ can take on if $x=1$. I thought about making it $i= x+ (\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n})$ but this evaluates to $x$. How would I represent this number $i$ for a given $x$?

I could represent it as $i=\text{min}(s)$ for $s \in (x,\infty)$ but this seems messy. I'm looking for a cleaner way to write this if possible

Comment: "How would I represent the number, i, that is one increment larger than x, where an increment is infinitely small."  You can't.  The concept is nonsense.

Comment: This smallest number $s$ does not exist. For a related concept, see the [infimum/greatest lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum)

Comment: "For example, if s∈(1,2), i would be the smallest number s can take on if x=1. "  No such number. "I could represent it as i=min(s) for s∈(x,x+1) "  There is no minimum in $(x,x+1)$. "I'm looking for a cleaner way to write this if possible"  It's not possible.  The concept is mathematically unsound and contradictory.

Comment: Are you working in the real numbers?

Comment: Define "increment."

Comment: @fleablood Certainly there's nothing like that concept in the real numbers or even most extensions of the reals that might include things worthy of being called "infinitely small", but I personally think "The concept is nonsense." is a step (an increment?) too far, if the OP didn't say they were working in the reals.

Comment: The number i is an equivalence class that contains many sequences. They all evaluate to the same i, but that does not hold you from picking one of them to convey further information. If you are picking the sequence you are not picking the equivalence class, so you don't say "smallest number" but just say using the approach ... or approaching with the sequence ...

Comment: Else, i + ε, as ε is often used for an arbitrarily small number.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the reading from Player3236's comment, I understand that this is not possible and more importantly why this is not possible. [examples to understand why for any future readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

i+1/∞

Why?

Short: Infinity is a deferred loop stop.

Infinity (∞) is a loop in an information processor (brain, computer),
that does never stop, like `while True: ...`.
Since the looping never stops it never gets into existence as such.
This kind of ∞ therefore does not exist.

Consequently ∞ is an infinite loop, where the stop is deferred to later.
The number of actual loops is thus defined by the need of the context.

The real numbers have a double infinite loop:
dense (arbitrarily precise) and infinite (arbitrarily large).

√2,... and also 1, 2,... ∈ℝ
do not exist other than
"depending on the situation we want this or that precision".
In the same sense ∞ means
"depending on the situation we want a number large enough".

So i+1/∞ means stop when close enough to i from above,
where the reader can decide what enough means in a situation.

Comment: Unless you provide a source, I think your definition of "$1/\infty$" is not standard at all.

Comment: The same as for 1+∞, which is quite common.
$1/∞ = \lim_{n->∞}{1/n}$ unless the writer maps the different descriptions
to different meaning in the text that precedes. It can make a difference in computation needs where to loop.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}1/n$ standardly equals $0$, not "stop when close enough to $0$ from above, where the reader can decide what enough means in a situation". If you want $1/\infty$ to have something to do with stopping close enough, then 1. I think that's not how it's defined in any major math text. and 2. you can't have $1/\infty=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}1/n$ unless you also have a definition of limit that disagrees with perhaps every math text that defines it.

Comment: $\lim_{n->∞}{1/n}$ says exactly loop until you are satisfied
in all math books.
That is how ℝ is defined, a set of sequences (loops) that never stop.
We talk about loops whenever we talk about an element of ℝ. $1 := \lim_{n->1} n$, ...

Comment: [Wikipedia agrees with me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Examples) that that limit is zero, and I have never seen a math book (e.g. one on calculus or real or complex analysis) define limits that way. But you claim that it "says exactly loop until you are satisfied in all math books". Unless you can provide the title of one such book, it seems we are at an impasse.

Comment: @Mark S: If this was sci.math 20+ years ago, I'd strongly suspect the OP of [trolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll). However, I'm less certain now, as the art of trolling has mostly vanished due to the noise-to-signal ratio having gotten so high in general on the internet.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Definition) "defining real numbers as equivalence classes of their Cauchy sequences " is how I learned ℝ in high school. That makes still sense to me now. I have no intention to troll. It is just, one needs to see the concept behind the symbols, which is often not done, or is also up to some interpretation.

Comment: $1∈ℝ$ is a different symbol than $1∈ℤ$.
As an equivalence class $1∈ℝ$ combines many sequences.
Depending on the situation you can pick one such sequence to convey further information.

Comment: Obviously, since "$1 \in \mathbb R$" uses $\mathbb R$ but not ${\mathbb Z},$ while "$1 \in \mathbb Z$" uses $\mathbb Z$ but not ${\mathbb R}.$ I think what you mean is that "$1$" as an element of $\mathbb R$ is different (under formal constructions of these sets) from "$1$" as an element of ${\mathbb Z}.$